# adding Mathematical formulas plugin to the ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ckeditor, mathjax

I am currently making a Quiz application with rails
in this my requirement is to have a Rich text editor like ckeditor with file handling and mathematical equation typing capabilities ckeditor gem is good fit but how to add Mathematical Formulas plugin to it .
A example will do the work..
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Update (April 12th 2017):**

I've updated the example using a new CDN, since MathJax is shutting down their CDN. Check out Peter's comment for more details.

Download the Mathematical Formulas plugin for CKeditor from:

http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax

In addition you will also need the following plugins:

```
lineutils
widget
```

Put all of the plugins in

```
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/
```

Edit/create the following file

```
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js
```

These are the settings that I use:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  // config.language = 'fr';
  // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
  config.extraPlugins = 'lineutils,mathjax,widget';

  // MathJax config
  config.mathJaxLib = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.allowedContent = true;

  // Toolbar groups configuration.
  config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'Mathjax' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
  ];
};
```

'Mathjax' is the button that opens the equation editor.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Wiris ([www.wiris.com](http://www.wiris.com)). I think it's more powerful than ckeditor.